# Change background for selected TreeViewItem in TreeView

Tags: uwp

How do you use a custom background color for the selected TreeViewItem in a TreeView without overriding the entire style?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedDisabled" Color="Transparent" />
</TreeView.Resources>
```